# How can I get the name of the student who has the max grant?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

[image]

I get this error:

> Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TOP`:

```
select top (1) name
from student s
order by grant desc;
```

The above returns one row always, even when there are ties for the highest grant.  If you want all such rows, you can add the `with ties` modifier:

```
select top (1) with ties name
from student s
order by grant desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SELECT [name]
FROM [student]
WHERE [grant] = (SELECT max([grant]) FROM [student])
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code can be correct if only one student has the max grant:

```
select top (1) name
    from student s
    order by grant desc;
```

if you have two or more student with the same grant, you should write as below:

```
select * from
(
select 
id,
name,
Dens_Rank() over (order by grant desc) student_rank
)temp where temp.student_rank=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below query -

SELECT
    *
FROM
    student
WHERE
    ROWNUM < 2
ORDER BY
    grant DESC;